# sql help getting data from all the followers ? ( like twitter if we follow )

Tags: php, sql, mysql, pdo, php-5.3

[image]

example if i have

```
follow table
company one ( cid = 1 ) following two ( cid = 2 )
company one ( cid = 1 ) following three( cid = 3 )

feeds table
company one ( cid = 1 ) type 'product' description 'hello ive updated a product';
company two ( cid = 2 ) type 'product' description 'hello ive updated a product im from company 2';
company three ( cid = 3 ) type 'shoutout' description 'hello ive i got a shoutout im company 3';
company one ( cid = 1 ) type 'product' description 'hello ive updated my second product';
```

question

**how do i get all the feeds.description from the company that my company ( example here is cid = 1 ) ?**

heres my simple pdo sql to get just mine.

```
    $data['feeds']['cid'] = 1;

    return $this->db->fetchAll("SELECT feeds.type, feeds.$type, feeds.cid, feeds.time, companies.name FROM feeds, companies WHERE 
    feeds.cid = :cid AND companies.cid = :cid ORDER BY feeds.fid DESC LIMIT 0, 5", $data['feeds']);

this will display
hello ive updated a product
hello ive updated my second product
```

maybe something like this ? ( fail )

```
    $data['feeds']['cid'] = 1,2,3;

    return $this->db->fetchAll("SELECT feeds.type, feeds.$type, feeds.cid, feeds.time, companies.name FROM feeds, companies WHERE 
    feeds.cid = :cid AND companies.cid = :cid ORDER BY feeds.fid DESC LIMIT 0, 5", $data['feeds']);

this should be displaying like
hello ive updated a product
hello ive updated a product im from company 2
hello ive i got a shoutout im company 3
hello ive updated my second product
```

or simpler get feeds.description from each follow.following ( cid = 1,2,3,etc ) from me. ( cid = 1)
or if twitter get all my friends status ( friends that i follow )

edit*

some good guys at irc mysql said to use joins. but i just dont get it.
what i get is this

```
fetch all the follow.following from cid = me ( example cid = 1 )
```

then

```
SELECT * FROM feeds WHERE feeds.cid = IN (2,3,cid that im following ( see follow.following ))
```

anyone can give me an example for joins in this problem ?

Comment: What is the value of `$type`?

Comment: ups btw there is an time in the feeds. somehow the image is somewhat error :D . the value of type is the type of the information like this is a 'shoutout' this is a 'updatestatus' or etc, so we could easily manage them lateron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, assuming that the question is "How do i get all the feeds.description from the company that my company IS FOLLOWING?" you want to join using the following key:

```
select 
companies.name, 
feeds.type, 
feeds.description 
from follow 
inner join feeds on (follow.following = feeds.cid or follow.cid = feeds.cid)
inner join companies on (feeds.cid = companies.cid)
where follow.cid = :cid
order by feeds.fid desc 
limit 5;
```

This should list all of the companies that your :cid (1) is following.

**EDIT:** Feeds should include my company's feeds + feeds my company is following.

Comment: but one more problem, where is our own feeds ?

Comment: So you're looking for your own company's feeds + the feeds that your company is following?

Comment: yes!, btw nice one. if i could i give you +50 :| but i have to wait 2 days. anyway some said that my database scema will not scale.

Comment: BTW... no problem. You post an ERD you deserve an answer.

Comment: in the name of kernel. how do i never think of that ( i was trying 3 hours already.

Comment: anyway do i need improvement to the erd ?

Comment: It's hard to say from the question. One thing I would definitely change is to make feeds.following a foreign key to companies (add an index, at least). How many companies / products / feeds are you expecting?

Comment: quite a lot. btw when we add fk its an index too isnt? btw yes ive add an fk, see the bottom feeds.company.uid_FK it means that feeds.cid is a FK to companies.cid

Comment: No, the following column is not indexed according to your ERD...

alter table follow add foreign key (following) references companies(CID);

Comment: ups everything is doubled, sorry up again :D